Removing duplicates from TEXTJOIN in google sheets
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q6iNB7V8_pvR6qQBLDolU9xU4pbj8M3NAPOu5TFFrPc/edit#gid=185521600
In the attached spreadsheet, I have a column on the "DATA PROCESSED" sheet called "Sites Visited" (col BT). In this column I have concatenated the "Site Name" columns from entries 1-10 but I would like to only return the first instance if the site name in entries 1-10 is duplicated.
In cell BU4 I tried this formula:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE({D4,J4,Q4,X4,AE4,AL4,AS4,AZ4,BG4,BN4}))
but it is still giving me duplicates (Office, Sheraton, Sheraton). I would like it to just return:
"Office, Sheraton"
Thanks in advance!!


the issue is you have a trailing space for one of the Sheraton  (Cell_J4 for example) which is causing the duplicate(s) although you are trying to unique it:
Alternatively you can use this single array-style formula:
=byrow(D3:BN,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,textjoin(", ",1,unique(filter(trim(Σ),D2:BN2="Site Name"),1)))))


You should enable the by_column argument of UNIQUE or replace the commas used to construct the array with semicolons.
Both of these formulas should work:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE({D4,J4,Q4,X4,AE4,AL4,AS4,AZ4,BG4,BN4},1))

=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE({D4;J4;Q4;X4;AE4;AL4;AS4;AZ4;BG4;BN4}))


You are making things complicated by omitting the travel column in Entry 1.  If you add that column in you can use the following formula:
=BYROW(A3:BS5, LAMBDA(rw, IF(LEN(INDEX(rw,,1)), TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, UNIQUE(MAP(SEQUENCE(70,1,0), LAMBDA(s, IF(MOD(s,7),,INDEX(rw,,s+3)))))),)))

Spaced out version:
=BYROW(A3:BS5, LAMBDA(rw, IF(LEN(INDEX(rw,,1)), 
   TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
     UNIQUE(
       MAP(SEQUENCE(70,1,0), LAMBDA(s,
         IF(MOD(s,7),,INDEX(rw,,s+3)))))),)))

In the SEQUENCE, 70 represents 7*10 entries. If the number of entries might change, it can be calculated dynamically by taking the largest number from your headings {"Entry 1","Entry 2",etc.} from their row.
For example, if those text strings are in row 1, then use 1:1. You can tweak it depending on your needs but based on the current format the following will return 70:
7*MAX(INDEX(RIGHT(1:1,2)*1))

and the formula would become:
=BYROW(A3:BS, LAMBDA(rw, IF(LEN(INDEX(rw,,1)), 
   TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
     UNIQUE(
       MAP(SEQUENCE(7*MAX(INDEX(RIGHT(1:1,2)*1)),1,0),
         LAMBDA(s, IF(MOD(s,7),,INDEX(rw,,s+3)))))),)))

